# How to parse the string response in android?

Tags: android, html, parsing, xml-parsing, response

I'd like to know what is the easiest way to write to and parse a XML file in Android. My requirement is very simple. A sample file would be something like:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Parsing HTML tags in JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539168/android-parsing-html-tags-in-json)

Comment: httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(requestEnvelope));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

Comment: Hi goody line is string

Comment: If you have the line in a String then can't you just see if the String `contains` the TITLE tag and then see what's after it, between the next '>' and '<' characters?

Comment: Can't you use stripHtml(line) ?
public String stripHtml(String html) {
  return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
 }

Comment: Thank you very much goody sharing help full information ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it i am using this simple format its working fine Thank you .

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

SAX is always the best option when parsing XML in android. you can use tutorial for SAX parsing

reference:[Click Here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sax-parsing-example/)